# Automatically download email

Tags: email, raspberry-pi

I recently got a raspberry pi and was wondering if it would be possible to program it to automatically receive new e-mails then download and save it as a text file

Comment: if there is a way, what would i need/ need to know in order to do it.

Comment: You should know the IMAP or POP protocol.

Comment: the protocols are somewhat trivial, standard sockets programming/api, etc.  all basic stuff. There are probably a zillion programs out there that already do this if you dont want to write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the python [imaplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html) to download mails from an IMAP server or [poplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/poplib.html) to download using the pop3 protocol, usually both are available. See the examples on both pages. Extending these to export the mails [into textfiles](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) should be easy! If you have any troubles, post a new question and paste the code you already have! good luck!